# Not response for request on docker shell

Tags: docker, url, request, vps, host

I've to send post request to URL, but there is a bad case here I'm facing. I can send post request only using server. It's because requesting URL server checks server address or something that rejects localhost or another server. if I send request on my server it's working fine, but if I send request with docker shell that on my server, it's not returning response.